# Error in sending email on live server

Tags: c#, .net, email

I am sending email using c#:

```
protected void SendEmailToVisitor(string Name, string Email, string Contact, string Message, string Subject)
{
    string myEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"];
    MailMessage objMail = new MailMessage();
    objMail.From = new MailAddress(myEmail);
    objMail.Subject = "Chanderraj.com";
    objMail.To.Add(Email);
    objMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    StringBuilder emailMessage = new StringBuilder();
    emailMessage.Append("<h2>Hi, "+Name+",</h2> <br/>");
    emailMessage.Append("Thank you for writing us. <br/><br/><br/>");
    emailMessage.Append("Best wishes from http://www.chanderraj.com");
    objMail.Body = emailMessage.ToString();
    SmtpClient objSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    objSmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
   // objSmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    objSmtpClient.Send(objMail);
    this.Reset();
    lblSent.Text = Name + ", your message sent.";
}

<system.net>
<mailSettings >
  <smtp>
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="chanderraj1989@gmail.com" enableSsl="true" password="xxxxxxxxxx" port="587" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

If i add enableSsl in config it shows configuration error  before page loads:
**Unrecognized attribute 'enableSsl'.**
may be this is due to older version of .NET on server.

So, i removed enablSsl from config and put it in code then it shows:

**The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true that for .NET 3 and earlier you can not use enableSSL property in config file. 
For your problem you can add line,

```
SmtpClient objSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
objSmtpClient.EnableSsl = true; // Add this line of code. Hope this works
```

Also add this line in your config file,

```
 <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="test@gmail.com">
```

For .NET 4: yes, You can use add the enableSSL tag in config section.

Comment: @donstack This code works at my side, can you just debug your code and   can you see after this line SmtpClient objSmtpClient = new SmtpClient(); objSmtpClient is having all the values i.e. host,credentials value assigned.

Comment: this code is working fine from development machine(.NET 4.0). and also i have tested on .net 4.0 live servers its not working. means mainly problem is live server not .net version

Comment: Same problem here ... any news?

Comment: now i am using email created on my hosting server and it is working

Comment: @donstack can you elaborate a little more what were you doing before and what changes have you made now, "email created on my hosting server" what it means?

Answer (score 0):

Not absolute solution but it worked.
As i have a domain chanderraj.com and a domain has option of creating emails like info@chanderraj.com. So i have created one and specified in my config file in place of Gmail id and password(shown in question).